# How to install Percona Xtrabackup to Ubuntu 12.04LTS?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Percona Xtrabackup to my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS insatlled on Amazon EC2.
I am trying to follow instruction on the Xtrabackup installation page [here](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/installation/apt_repo.html). The instruction follows as

*Add this to /etc/apt/sources.list, replacing squeeze with the name of your distribution:*

```
deb http://repo.percona.com/apt squeeze main
deb-src http://repo.percona.com/apt squeeze main
```

In my case I will replace *squeeze* with *precise* but when I open /etc/apt/sources.list for editing it says the following

[image]

It is suggestion three alternatives instead of editing which are listed a.), b.) and c.).

**My Question**

What should I do to install Percona Xtrabackup to my box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's more elegant to create a new file in the `sources.list.d` directory. It should have the 'extension' `.list` though. Just create a new file for example `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/percona.list` to contain

```
deb http://repo.percona.com/apt precise main
deb-src http://repo.percona.com/apt precise main
```

And don't forget to follow the rest of the instructions (GPG APT key, update).

For Amazon EC2 you actually ought to do so apparently, as explained perfectly in the comment you posted.

It's more elegant, because `.d` directories are meant for users to put their own part of the configuration in there and scripts modifying this when running dist-upgrades for example are less likely to break.